# Unity freezes for 2 seconds while Microsoft Azure Text-To-Speech processes input

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Azure Text To Speech with Unity. How it works is when a button is pressed to produce a speech from text input, the whole app freezes for about 2 seconds then outputs the sound and the game resumes back to normal. I assume this freeze is due to Azure is processing TTS? Below is the code.

```
public void ButtonClick()
    {
        // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
        // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("[redacted]", "westus");

        // Creates a speech synthesizer.
        // Make sure to dispose the synthesizer after use!
        using (var synthsizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null))
        {
            lock (threadLocker)
            {
                waitingForSpeak = true;
            }

            // Starts speech synthesis, and returns after a single utterance is synthesized.
            var result = synthsizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputField.text).Result;

            // Checks result.
            string newMessage = string.Empty;
            if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
            {
                // Since native playback is not yet supported on Unity yet (currently only supported on Windows/Linux Desktop),
                // use the Unity API to play audio here as a short term solution.
                // Native playback support will be added in the future release.
                var sampleCount = result.AudioData.Length / 2;
                var audioData = new float[sampleCount];
                for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
                {
                    audioData[i] = (short)(result.AudioData[i * 2 + 1] << 8 | result.AudioData[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
                }

                // The default output audio format is 16K 16bit mono
                var audioClip = AudioClip.Create("SynthesizedAudio", sampleCount, 1, 16000, false);
                audioClip.SetData(audioData, 0);
                audioSource.clip = audioClip;
                audioSource.Play();

                newMessage = "Speech synthesis succeeded!";
            }
            else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
            {
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                newMessage = $"CANCELED:\nReason=[{cancellation.Reason}]\nErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]\nDid you update the subscription info?";
            }

            lock (threadLocker)
            {
                message = newMessage;
                waitingForSpeak = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (inputField == null)
        {
            message = "inputField property is null! Assign a UI InputField element to it.";
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(message);
        }
        else if (speakButton == null)
        {
            message = "speakButton property is null! Assign a UI Button to it.";
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Continue with normal initialization, Text, InputField and Button objects are present.
            inputField.text = "Enter text you wish spoken here.";
            message = "Click button to synthesize speech";
            speakButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClick);
            //ButtonClick();
        }
    }
```

I'd like the TTS to ideally not freeze the whole app when the TTS button is pressed, so the app is useable when the TTS button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputField.text).Result;`  it blocks until the task is complete. Instead, try calling `Task<SpeechSynthesisResult> task = synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputField.text);` then setting up a coroutine that yields until `task.IsCompleted()` is true then does the rest of the procedure you have in your code

Here's a partial (untested) solution to get you started. I changed the variable to **synthesizer** from *synthsizer*, and I removed all the locking because coroutines happen sequentially on the main thread so no locking is necessary:

```
public void ButtonClick()
{
    if (waitingForSpeak) return;

    waitingForSpeak = true;

    // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription
    // key and service region.
    // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
    SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("[redacted]", "westus");

    // Creates a speech synthesizer.
    // Make sure to dispose the synthesizer after use!       
    SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null));

    // Starts speech synthesis, and returns after a single utterance is synthesized.
    Task<SpeechSynthesisResult> task = synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inputField.text);

    StartCoroutine(CheckSynthesizer(task, config, synthesizer));
}

private IEnumerator CheckSynthesizer(Task<SpeechSynthesisResult> task, 
        SpeechConfig config, 
        SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted());

    var result = task.Result;

    // Checks result.
    string newMessage = string.Empty;
    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
    {
        // Since native playback is not yet supported on Unity yet (currently
        // only supported on Windows/Linux Desktop),
        // use the Unity API to play audio here as a short term solution.
        // Native playback support will be added in the future release.
        var sampleCount = result.AudioData.Length / 2;
        var audioData = new float[sampleCount];
        for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
        {
            audioData[i] = (short)(result.AudioData[i * 2 + 1] << 8 
                    | result.AudioData[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
        }

        // The default output audio format is 16K 16bit mono
        var audioClip = AudioClip.Create("SynthesizedAudio", sampleCount, 
                1, 16000, false);
        audioClip.SetData(audioData, 0);
        audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        audioSource.Play();

        newMessage = "Speech synthesis succeeded!";
    }
    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
    {
        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
        newMessage = $"CANCELED:\nReason=[{cancellation.Reason}]\n"+
                     $"ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]\n"+"
                     "Did you update the subscription info?";
    }

    message = newMessage;
    waitingForSpeak = false;
    synthesizer.Dispose();
}

void Start()
{
    if (inputField == null)
    {
        message = "inputField property is null! Assign a UI InputField element to it.";
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(message);
    }
    else if (speakButton == null)
    {
        message = "speakButton property is null! Assign a UI Button to it.";
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(message);
    }
    else
    {
        // Continue with normal initialization, Text, InputField and Button 
        // objects are present.
        inputField.text = "Enter text you wish spoken here.";
        message = "Click button to synthesize speech";
        speakButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClick);
        //ButtonClick();
    }
}
```

---

In response to the comments, here's a start to an alternative method you could try that wraps the data copying in a task and yields until that task is complete:

```
private IEnumerator CheckSynthesizer(Task<SpeechSynthesisResult> task, 
        SpeechConfig config, 
        SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted());

    var result = task.Result;

    // Checks result.
    string newMessage = string.Empty;
    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
    {
        // Since native playback is not yet supported on Unity yet (currently
        // only supported on Windows/Linux Desktop),
        // use the Unity API to play audio here as a short term solution.
        // Native playback support will be added in the future release.

        Task copyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
        {
            var sampleCount = result.AudioData.Length / 2;
            var audioData = new float[sampleCount];
            for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
            {
                audioData[i] = (short)(result.AudioData[i * 2 + 1] << 8 
                        | result.AudioData[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
            }

            // The default output audio format is 16K 16bit mono
            var audioClip = AudioClip.Create("SynthesizedAudio", sampleCount, 
                    1, 16000, false);
            audioClip.SetData(audioData, 0);
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            audioSource.Play();
        });

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => copyTask.IsCompleted());

        newMessage = "Speech synthesis succeeded!";
    }
    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
    {
        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
        newMessage = $"CANCELED:\nReason=[{cancellation.Reason}]\n"+
                     $"ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]\n"+"
                     "Did you update the subscription info?";
    }

    message = newMessage;
    waitingForSpeak = false;
    synthesizer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it also make sense to make a Task<float[]> for the for-loop that converts the AudioData byte array to the audioDatafloat array? There's still a tiny bit of freezing going on, which i presume could possibly be the for loop thats also causing some delay. That way it will wait for the for loop to finish before executing the remaining code in the Coroutine?

Comment: Hmm it could be worth a shot, creating that task and then yielding until that task is complete like you to with the other one.

Comment: Here's what the task for the for loop looks like. Is this correct? `private Task<float[]> longForLoop(SpeechSynthesisResult result)
    {
        var sampleCount = result.AudioData.Length / 2;
        var audioData = new float[sampleCount];

        for (var i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i)
        {
            audioData[i] = (short)(result.AudioData[i * 2 + 1] << 8 | result.AudioData[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(audioData);
    } `

Comment: This is getting a bit out of my expertise but I went ahead and edited my answer and tried to include a start to that. If you have any big issues trying that, I would start [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), being sure to include the code in the question and describe the lag that happens when you run it.